# Creating new datagridview column formatting

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` on my form.  I am trying to format a column to show as currency.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
this.employeeInfoDataGridView.Columns["Salary"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
```

Got this error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in...

I am using this on `form_load` if that makes a difference.

Comment: try this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029542/currency-culture-formatting-not-applying-on-datagridview-column/14031179#14031179)

Comment: have you even loaded the DGV with a datatable? Can you show the code where you load the DGV?

Comment: Yes it populates all of the data correctly just trying to format one of the columns.

Comment: @Code_Help - if the datagridview is binded to db and columns are autogenerated then put the code in DataBindingComplete event handler

Comment: @Junaith I have done this many times in the form_load, it may not be best practice, but it is not the cause of the exception.

Comment: @Code_Help Show us how you load the DGV with your table

Comment: see edit this is my entire form code.  I tried adding it to databindingcomplete event with same exception.

Comment: @Code_Help - Is the Column name is "Salary" or its HeaderText is "Salary"? You should use the column name not the header text to get the column.

Comment: I am not sure what the difference is?  When I click server explorer the database > table name > column is Salary.  This is the column I want to format as currency instead of decimal like it is now.

Comment: Any idea what I can do to make this work correctly?  i just want to sort the Salary column as currency.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out by going into my form > clicking datagridview object > columns property > salary column > default cell style > format > c2.

Still confused as to why I couldn't do it in code the same way.  Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

'System.NullReferenceException' occurs when the particular column named 'Salary' is not yet being created during form_load. In this case, you need to do the following in order to avoid this exception:

```
if ( this.employeeInfoDataGridView.Columns["Salary"] != null )
{
    this.employeeInfoDataGridView.Columns["Salary"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
}
```

And you have to ensure that the specific column is loaded before you set the DefaultCellStyle of that column.